# Is there any new api to show notification properly on honeycomb?

Tags: android

Is there any new api to show notification properly on honeycomb?

I run my android app using ginger bread notification on honeycomb, my notification has progress bar, and whenever I update it, the notification bar blinks.

Is there anything to avoid this side effect?

Thank you.

Comment: it's not API problem ... problem is in your update code ...

Comment: can you please elaborate what is the problem in my update code. I have a custom notification and it has a progress bar. I need to update the progress bar periodically in order to update the progress bar.

Comment: it was a little bit ironic comment ... you didn't show us any code ... so i'm assuming that is your fault ... provide minimal code sample to get this effect ... remeber that if you run this code on emulator it can blink coz it's soooooo slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your issue is the same I was experiencing, but I found I needed to make sure I was using the `FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE` flag with my notification or else the notification would keep displaying as if it were a new one every time I updated it.

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
```

Even without this flag, it worked properly prior to Honeycomb.  Honeycomb obviously utilizes this flag differently than prior releases.